# An example for ring with trivial ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I know that if there exists no ideal different from trivial ideals, the commutative ring with unity is a field. But I cannot figure out any example for a ring has trivial ideals only and not a field.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, if it's a commutative ring with unity, you get a field. So looking at non-commutative rings, or rings without unity might be a good place to start.

Comment: HINT: The noncommutative rings that most people are most familiar with are the rings of matrices over a field.

Comment: Aren't quaternions a decent example?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Does $Mat_2(\mathbb R)$ work?

Comment: You tell me; or you figure it out.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739205/show-that-m-2-mathbbr-has-no-non-trivial-two-sided-ideals