# Prove that ideal is whole ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Prove that if $I$ is an ideal of the ring $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $X= \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\in I$, then $I=M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

I think the question is wrong because
there is no matrix $A\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $AX=I_2$ or $XA=I_2$, so $I_2$ is not in this ideal hence $I\neq M_2(\mathbb{R}).$

Am I correct?

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739205/show-that-m-2-mathbbr-has-no-non-trivial-two-sided-ideals) for the general case.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider $AX$ and $XA$ where $A$ is a permutation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is wrong because the ideal generated by one element in a non-commutative setting does not only include its left multiples and right multiples.

Comment: As I understand correctly, there is also sum of elements in ideal. Connecting those 2 conditions, we looking for matrix $A$ such that $A.X+X.A$ is identity matrix. Considering answer below, for matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ we got identity matrix in result.