# Proof that ideal is whole ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ideals

I have a question as follows:

> Let
> $$A = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
> Prove that the ideal $\left<A\right>$ of the ring $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is the whole ring.

I took some advice from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049935/prove-that-ideal-is-whole-ring), and tried to find a matrix $X$ which would give me an identity matrix for $AX + XA$.
However, it seems any matrix I would try to multiply A with results in the first element being zero because of the zero elements in $A$. My initial thought was that this has something to do with A already being a part of the identity matrix equation. Am I anywhere near the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the ring of matrices over a field simple?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22629/why-is-the-ring-of-matrices-over-a-field-simple)

Answer (score 1):

Note the following:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 & 1\\
1 &
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
&  \\
& 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
 & 1\\
1 &
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \\
 &
\end{bmatrix} =: \boldsymbol B, 
$$
and $\boldsymbol A + \boldsymbol B = \boldsymbol I_2$. By the definition of an ideal, $\boldsymbol B \in I, \boldsymbol A + \boldsymbol B \in I$, hence $I = \mathrm M_2(\Bbb R)$.

Another thing to correct:

It should be

> Prove that the ideal containing $\boldsymbol A$ is the whole ring.